# 2D matrix for labelbinarizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

There is one behavior of [labelbinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit(np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]))
lb.classes_
```

The output is `array([0, 1, 2])`. Why there is a 2 there?

Comment: So is your problem solved?

Comment: @VivekKumar yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have passed a 2-d label-indicator matrix.

A label indicator matrix is mostly used in multi-label problems where more than one labels can be present for a sample. So how do we represent them:

```
           class 1     class 2     class 3
sample1      0           1            1
sample2      1           0            0
sample3
...
```

0 means the label is not present and 1 means thats present. So for your current 
supplied matrix how many classes are there? -- 3

So they are represented using 0,1,2.